# Linear Optimization - Putting gaps between scheduled items?

Tags: linear-programming

I'm playing around with linear programming for schedule optimization, and I'm using ojAlgo although that shouldn't matter.

The scenario is I have several university classes each with variables start time `S` and end time `E`. Assume there is only one room I am scheduling against, and I just want to get possible `S` and `E` times for each one without overlap.

I need to express an additional rule that for given two consecutive classes, they must be 15 minutes (1 discrete interval) apart between the end time of the first class `Ei` and the start time of the second class `Sj`, or vice versa with `Ej` and `Si`.

I felt like I could use some binary tricks [like I asked in this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480793/linear-programming-preventing-staff-scheduling-shift-overlap), so I did something like this. `b` is a binary that can only be elements 1,0.

`Ei - Sj >= 1 - 100000b
Ej - Si >= 1 - 100000(1-b)`

This seemed to work great for the following proofs:

`Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=10, Ej=11, b=1, SUCCESS
Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=10, Ej=11, b=0, FAIL
Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=6, Ej=7, b=1, SUCCESS
Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=6, Ej=7, b=0, FAIL
Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=9, Ej=10, b=0, FAIL`

But I got a false positive with this:

`Si=8, Ei=9, Sj=6, Ej=7, b=1,SUCCESS`

Is there a way I can alternate effectively with a binary between `Ei - Sj >= 1` and `Ej - Si >= 1` ?

Comment: Why not just set Ei - Si >= length of task i + 1 ? Then each class naturally takes up the extra break time after it. Then you just need the usual algorithm for no two overlapping classes.

Comment: Well right now my model in ojAlgo is packing things together tightly when they don't have to. The result is huge blocks of empty space, and busy blocks packed back-to-back with classes.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Just hack it and manually chop off those extra 15 minutes later.

Comment: I'd still like to see how a binary would be used, because I have several problems of this nature. like limiting the working time each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment does not look correct at all:

```
Ei - Sj >= 1 - 100000b
Ej - Si >= 1 - 100000(1-b)
```

This means

$$\begin{align} &E_i \ge S_j+1\\&\text{or}\\
&E_j \ge S_i+1\end{align}$$

This has no practical physical meaning. It will allow something like:

[image]

I think you want:

$$\begin{align} &S_i \ge E_j+1\\&\text{or}\\
&S_j \ge E_i+1\end{align}$$

This will enforce:

[image]

Comment: I gave myself the impression that the order of placement of start and end time into the equation could be arbitrary, as long as you were consistent for both equations. Let me think about this and then test it in my model tonight....

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense with your visuals now

Comment: This worked great. Thank you.